# .NET how to monitor db connection interruption?

Tags: c#, .net, database

Is there any way how to monitor database connection for interruptions? I have one connection shared across applications and some objects should react on connection interruption.

Ideally it should be an event. The only thing I found is a connection exception, but it is raised locally (where I am listening for exceptions).

I have idea to inherit from `DbConnection` and listen for exception in this object (overloading its methods), raising signal on connection error exception (by related code). But maybe there is simplest way.

Thank you of ideas.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Some processes (objects) should stop its work on connection interruption and wait for reconnection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sharing a single connection is never good and it **IS** a bad practice. The main reason is actually your problem.
I suggest you change your design a bit (not a big deal) and rely on the ADO.NET **connection pooling**. It's a must have in case you don't want to run into all kinds of bottlenecks, especially in multithreading situations.

It means that all your connections are transient and you create one only when you need to go to the database.

You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx), where you can also find samples on how to use it. The main thing to know about it is that it uses the Disposable pattern.

```
//Notice the **using ** block
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) 
{
  conn.Open();
  //do something with the connection.
  //as soon as the using block ends, the managed connection is disposed and released in the pool
}
```

Comment: Got to stick with @thecoon here. You could probably manage to write such a thing, but it would be overkill or very fragile, and still wouldn't solve the underlying issue, that you shouldn't be persisting a connection by default.

Comment: Ouch. :-) Yes, it makes sense. So instead of distributing connection I will be distributing connection string.

Comment: @Fanda: yes, something like that. You could store it in a singleton properties class or something similar.

Comment: Now I am thinking how stop some processes, when connection is interrupted (or can't be opened). App is running in more threads. I have firebird and sql connecions, and some processes should stop on corruption of one of them. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It all depends on the design of your app. One option is to propagate the exception from `conn.Open()` to upper layers, where you can make a decision on what to do (stop or pause some other threads).

Comment: But I have 3 threads working with database (1 worker, 2 event listeners). In such case I can imagine to use one shared object (connection manager) and WaitHandle or something similar. Do you have any idea how to solve this?